# Route traffic between OpenVPN network and IPSec

Tags: routing, openvpn, linux-networking, ipsec

On the Server are two connection established (IPSec and from OpenVPN client). On the server I see subnet in IPSec, but not from OpenVPN client. 
On the server is firewalld active, here is public zone:

```
    public (active)
      target: default
      icmp-block-inversion: no
      interfaces: eth0 eth1
      sources:
      services: cockpit dhcpv6-client openvpn ssh
      ports: 500/udp 4500/udp
      protocols:
      masquerade: no
      forward-ports:
      source-ports:
      icmp-blocks:
      rich rules:
        rule protocol value="esp" accept
```

and dmz zone with tun0 interface

```
dmz (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: tun0
  sources:
  services: ssh
  ports:
  protocols:
  masquerade: yes
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

here is route table:

```
default via publicIP dev eth0 proto static metric 100
10.8.0.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.1
10.19.0.0/16 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.19.0.5 metric 100
10.19.0.0/16 via 10.19.0.1 dev eth0 proto static metric 100
publicNET/20 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src publicIP metric 100
```

Thank you for your advice!

#### UPDATE

ip xfrm policy:

```
src 10.19.0.0/16 dst 192.168.178.0/24
    dir out priority 379519 ptype main
    tmpl src SERVER1 dst SERVER2
        proto esp spi 0x4a7f1596 reqid 71 mode tunnel
src 192.168.178.0/24 dst 10.19.0.0/16
    dir fwd priority 379519 ptype main
    tmpl src SERVER2 dst SERVER1
        proto esp reqid 71 mode tunnel
src 192.168.178.0/24 dst 10.19.0.0/16
    dir in priority 379519 ptype main
    tmpl src SERVER2 dst SERVER1
        proto esp reqid 71 mode tunnel
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0
    socket in priority 0 ptype main
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0
    socket out priority 0 ptype main
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0
    socket in priority 0 ptype main
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0
    socket out priority 0 ptype main
src ::/0 dst ::/0
    socket in priority 0 ptype main
src ::/0 dst ::/0
    socket out priority 0 ptype main
src ::/0 dst ::/0
    socket in priority 0 ptype main
src ::/0 dst ::/0
    socket out priority 0 ptype main
```

Here is Strongswan config:

```
# Add connections here.
conn %default
        left=SERVER1
        leftsourceip=SERVER1
        leftid=SERVER1
        leftsubnet=10.19.0.0/16
        authby=secret
        auto=start

conn home
        ike=aes256-sha-modp1024
        esp=aes256-sha1-modp1024
        right=SERVER2
        rightid=@SERVER2
        rightsubnet=192.168.178.0/24
        ikelifetime=3600s
        keylife=3600s
```

#### UPDATE #2

ipsec.conf

```
conn %default
        left=SERVER1
        leftsourceip=SERVER1
        leftid=SERVER1
        leftsubnet=10.19.0.0/16,10.8.0.0/24
        authby=secret
        auto=start
```

xfrm policy:

```
src 10.8.0.0/24 dst 192.168.178.0/24
    dir out priority 375423 ptype main
    tmpl src SERVER1 dst SERVER2
        proto esp spi 0xc4247488 reqid 3 mode tunnel
src 192.168.178.0/24 dst 10.8.0.0/24
    dir fwd priority 375423 ptype main
    tmpl src SERVER2 dst SERVER1
        proto esp reqid 3 mode tunnel
src 192.168.178.0/24 dst 10.8.0.0/24
    dir in priority 375423 ptype main
    tmpl src SERVER2 dst SERVER1
        proto esp reqid 3 mode tunnel
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0
    socket in priority 0 ptype main
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0
    socket out priority 0 ptype main
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0
    socket in priority 0 ptype main
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0
    socket out priority 0 ptype main
src ::/0 dst ::/0
    socket in priority 0 ptype main
src ::/0 dst ::/0
    socket out priority 0 ptype main
src ::/0 dst ::/0
    socket in priority 0 ptype main
src ::/0 dst ::/0
    socket out priority 0 ptype main
```

aswell direct rules for firewalld:

```
<direct>
  <rule ipv="ipv4" table="nat" chain="POSTROUTING" priority="0">-m policy --pol ipsec --dir out -j ACCEPT</rule>
  <rule ipv="ipv4" table="filter" chain="FORWARD" priority="0">-s 192.168.178.0/24 -j DROP</rule>
  <rule ipv="ipv4" table="filter" chain="FORWARD" priority="0">-d 192.168.178.0/24 -j DROP</rule>
  <rule ipv="ipv4" table="filter" chain="FORWARD" priority="0">-s 192.168.178.0/24 -d 10.19.0.0/16 -m policy --dir in --pol ipsec -j ACCEPT</rule>
  <rule ipv="ipv4" table="filter" chain="FORWARD" priority="0">-s 192.168.178.0/24 -d 10.8.0.0/24 -m policy --dir in --pol ipsec -j ACCEPT</rule>
  <rule ipv="ipv4" table="filter" chain="FORWARD" priority="0">-s 10.19.0.0/16 -d 192.168.178.0/24 -m policy --dir out --pol ipsec -j ACCEPT</rule>
  <rule ipv="ipv4" table="filter" chain="FORWARD" priority="0">-s 10.8.0.0/24 -d 192.168.178.0/24 -m policy --dir out --pol ipsec -j ACCEPT</rule>
</direct>
```

and openvpn server config:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
user nobody
group nobody
persist-key
persist-tun
keepalive 10 120
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "dhcp-option DNS 176.103.130.130"
push "dhcp-option DNS 176.103.130.131"
#push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "route 192.168.178.0 255.255.255.0"
dh none
ecdh-curve prime256v1
tls-crypt tls-crypt.key 0
crl-verify crl.pem
ca ca.crt
cert server_21QCUO0cRXlOaJFT.crt
key server_21QCUO0cRXlOaJFT.key
auth SHA256
cipher AES-128-GCM
ncp-ciphers AES-128-GCM
tls-server
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-ECDHE-ECDSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256
status /var/log/openvpn/status.log
verb 3
```

Comment: When working with IPSec, you also have to check the `xfrm` policies, which decide whether to encrypt or drop packets. Edit your question and add the output of `ip xfrm policy show src 10/8 dst 10/8`.

Comment: This command give nothing back

Comment: You can try without the filter condition: `ip xfrm policy`

Comment: above is the output

Comment: The policy only allows forwarding between `192.168.178.0/24` (local network on the other side of the tunnel, I presume) and `10.19.0.0/16`. You might want to extend it to `10.0.0.0/8` (`left|rightsubnetwork` if you use `ipsec.conf` or `local|remote_ts` if you use `swanctl.conf`). You may add the configuration file for IPSec to the question.

Comment: I've updated topic. Thank you! Could you pls tell me, how could I extend correctly the policy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to configure routing between IPSec clients and OpenVPN clients, you must add `10.8.0.0/24` to the `leftsubnet` option. Your `%default` section should look like:

```
conn %default
    # IKEv1 does not support multiple subnets.
    keyexchange=ikev2
    left=SERVER1
    leftsourceip=SERVER1
    leftid=SERVER1
    leftsubnet=10.19.0.0/16,10.8.0.0/24
    authby=secret
    auto=start
```

This will add on each client:

1. an additional route (in table `220`, cf. `ip route show table 220`) of the form `10.8.0.0/24 via <real_gateway> dev <real_interface>`.
2. three additional `xfrm` policies, which state that traffic between `10.8.0.0/24` and `192.168.178.0/24` must be **encrypted** and sent to `SERVER1`.

To configure routing in the other direction add:

```
push "route 192.168.178.0 255.255.255.0"
```

to the OpenVPN server config.

After reloading both **charon** and the **OpenVPN** server, only the firewall may stand in the way of bidirectional communication. You might want to add the following rules:

```
# Insert instead of append, so the order is reversed
# 3. Drop the remaining (unencrypted) traffic from/to IPSec tunnel.
#    This will block private traffic from reaching the Internet,
#    when the tunnel is down.
iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.178.0/24 -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -d 192.168.178.0/24 -j DROP
# 2. Allow encrypted traffic from IPSec tunnel
iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.178.0/24 -d 10.19.0.0/16 \
    -m policy --dir in --pol ipsec -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.178.0/24 -d 10.8.0.0/24 \
    -m policy --dir in --pol ipsec -j ACCEPT
# 1. Allow encrypted traffic to IPSec tunnel
iptables -I FORWARD -s 10.19.0.0/16 -d 192.168.178.0/24 \
    -m policy --dir out --pol ipsec -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -s 10.8.0.0/24 -d 192.168.178.0/24 \
    -m policy --dir out --pol ipsec -j ACCEPT
```

or their **firewalld** equivalent.

Comment: Added update#2 but not traffic between subnets. But if firewalld is stopped,  I can access subnet 192.168.178.0

Comment: Check the firewall settings, especially the order of the rules. In the answer they are in reversed order, so the order will be correct when inserting (`-I`) at the top of the chain. If possible disable the firewall and put an `iptables -A FORWARD -j LOG` rule to log forwarded traffic (into the kernel's log ring, accessible, e.g. through `journalctl -k` or `dmesg`).

Comment: here is the subnets communication after ipsec reconnect: https://pastebin.com/JQULpnxR

Comment: I've reseted everything. Now I have only route push in openvpn server and direct rule in firewalld: <rule ipv="ipv4" table="nat" chain="POSTROUTING" priority="0">-s 10.8.0.0/24 -d 192.168.178.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source 10.19.0.5</rule> And everything work after reboot

Comment: The log shows a bidirectional communication between `10.8.0.2` and `192.168.178.1`, which was your goal.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved with static route in ovpn and iptables rule:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p all -s 10.8.0.0/24 -d 192.168.178.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source 10.19.0.5
```